Como mostrar todo el contenido de una caja ordenado?
Tengo un calendario fullcalendar que no he creado yo , donde se muestran citas.
Los estilos están predeterminados por Bootstrap, pero no consigo modificarlos, no entiendo como funcionan.
Las citas muestran: nombre del servicio, fecha, hora, personal que atiende el servicio y el cliente.
Cuando hay citas, estas se muestran en una caja de color verde. Sin embargo, el contenido no se muestra por completo. Lo que quiero decir, es que la caja tiene determinada medida y no muestra todo el contenido.
Muestro una captura del error:

Se puedo ver el codigo completo en Codepen
Es una aplicación Codelgniter, en lo que soy nuevo.
Tengo un aparado don de añadir mi propio css, pero hice varios intenté sin éxito:
.fc-timegrid-event {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: normal;
height: auto;
}

.fc-event-main-frame, .fc-event-title-container, .fc-event-title {
white-space: normal;
overflow: visible;
}

.fc-timegrid-event-harness {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
height: auto;
}

.fc-timegrid-event {
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.fc-timegrid-event:hover {
z-index: 2;
}

////////////
También probe:
.fc-timegrid-event {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden; /* Asegura que el contenido no se desborde */
white-space: normal; /* Permite que el texto se envuelva */
height: auto; /* Permite que la altura se ajuste al contenido */
}

.fc-event-main-frame, .fc-event-title-container, .fc-event-title {white-space: normal;
overflow: visible;}
.fc-timegrid-event-harness {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
height: auto; 
z-index: 1;
}

.fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
height: auto; 
}

No es posible mostrar todo el contenido.
Mostrare todo el elemento que muestra la caja que contiene la cita:
¿como hacer para que se muestre todo el contenido de la cita en la caja verde?
Este es el calendario, no esta completo por exceso de codigo.
Se puede ver completo en este enlace a Codepen:


<div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body mt-4">
                <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard"><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness"><div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><table class="fc-col-header " style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="fc-timegrid-axis"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame"></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">lun 24/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">mar 25/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">mié 26/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">jue 27/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">vie 28/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">sáb 29/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">dom 30/6</a></div></th></tr></tbody></table></div></div></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-body "><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness"><div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><div class="fc-daygrid-body fc-daygrid-body-unbalanced fc-daygrid-body-natural" style="width: 884px;"><table class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-table" style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-axis fc-scrollgrid-shrink"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame fc-timegrid-axis-frame-liquid"><span class="fc-timegrid-axis-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">Todo el día</span></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section"><td class="fc-timegrid-divider fc-cell-shaded"></td></tr><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-body  fc-scrollgrid-section-liquid"><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness fc-scroller-harness-liquid"><div class="fc-scroller fc-scroller-liquid-absolute" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><div class="fc-timegrid-body" style="width: 884px;"><div class="fc-timegrid-slots"><table class="" style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="00:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">0</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="00:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="00:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="00:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="01:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">1</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="01:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="01:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="01:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="02:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">2</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="02:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="02:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="02:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="03:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">3</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="03:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="03:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="03:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="04:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">4</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="04:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="04:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="04:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="05:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">5</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="05:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="05:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="05:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="06:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">6</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="06:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="06:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="06:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="07:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">7</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="07:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="07:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="07:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="08:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">8</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="08:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="08:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="08:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="09:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">9</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="09:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="09:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="09:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="10:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">10</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="10:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="10:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="10:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="11:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">11</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="11:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="11:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="11:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="12:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">12</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="12:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="12:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="12:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="13:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">13</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="13:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="13:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="13:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="14:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">14</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="14:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="14:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="14:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="15:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">15</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="15:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="15:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="15:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="16:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">16</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="16:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="16:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="16:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="17:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">17</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="17:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="17:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="17:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="18:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">18</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="18:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="18:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="18:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="19:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">19</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="19:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="19:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="19:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="20:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">20</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="20:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="20:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="20:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="21:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">21</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="21:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="21:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="21:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="22:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">22</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="22:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="22:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="22:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="23:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">23</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="23:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="23:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="23:30:00"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-timegrid-cols"><table style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-timegrid-axis"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-past" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (10:00-10:30) at 25-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 517px 0% -564px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">11:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (11:00-11:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 517px 0% -564px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">11:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (11:00-11:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Farrukito</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 752px 0% -799px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">16:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (16:00-16:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:00-10:30) at 27-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: </div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 501px 0% -548px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:40</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:40-11:00) at 27-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:00-10:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (10:00-10:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: hugo</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 799px 0% -846px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">17:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (17:00-17:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Federico</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>




a pesar de todo el codigo que has agregado no veo cual es el error ... o donde esta el codigo relacionado al error ...

ESto no tiene nada que ver ni con PHP, ni con Javascript, ni con codeigniter, esto es netamente CSS ...

y para arreglarlo tienes que inspeccionar en HTML los elementos y ver que reglas CSS son las que afectan las cajas verder y evaluar que Cambios al CSS deberian corregir el error...

una vez realizado lo anterior, de no lo lograr que se vea como quieres, entonces actualiza haca  el post incluye todo lo nuevo que has realizado y que intentaste para corregirlo y de ese punto entonces arrancamos nosotros... de momento no tenemos forma de ayudarte. ya que como dices no hay un error detectado si no una vista y una solicitud de correccion ...

Gracias por tu colaboración, quizá yo sea un poco especial. Seguire buscando, eto ya se alarga inutilmente y al parecer mi consulta no tiene sentido. Gracias de nuevo

En el minuto 1:12 de este video https://help.acuityscheduling.com/hc/en-us/articles/16676949879309-Test-your-scheduler puedes comprobar que el comportamiento de la cita viene a ser el mismo que el fullcalendar, el thunderbird y google calendar. La caja ocupa el espacio asignado por su tiempo, y si la descripcion que tiene fuera más larga apareceria truncado, como en todos los otros casos.

Es parte de la funcionalidad de un calendario que los eventos se ajusten a la franja horaria.  De lo contrario la vista calendario pierde todo sentido y para eso muestras los eventos en una lista
Lo que yo haría es disminuir el texto, por ejemplo tienes:
Corte de Niño - (10:00-10:30) at 25-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Miguel

Quito la fecha y hora, porque esa información ya está presente en el calendario y las palabras "Personal" y "Cliente" las cambio un icono
Corte de Niño|‍:Ezequiel|‍♀️:Miguel

También puedes agregar algo de estilo CSS, para que cuando el cursor se posicione sobre el evento la caja aumente de tamaño


.fc-timegrid-event-harness:hover{
 z-index:9999 !important;
}
.fc-event-start:hover {
   height: max-content;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 2px #00000080;  
}
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.14/index.global.min.js
"></script>

<div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body mt-4">
                <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard"><div class="fc-header-toolbar fc-toolbar fc-toolbar-ltr"><div class="fc-toolbar-chunk"><div class="fc-button-group"><button class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button" aria-label="prev"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-chevron-left"></span></button><button class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button" aria-label="next"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-chevron-right"></span></button></div><button disabled="" class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button">Hoy</button></div><div class="fc-toolbar-chunk"><h2 class="fc-toolbar-title">24 – 30 jun 2024</h2></div><div class="fc-toolbar-chunk"><div class="fc-button-group"><button class="fc-dayGridMonth-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button">Mes</button><button class="fc-timeGridWeek-button fc-button fc-button-primary fc-button-active" type="button">Semana</button><button class="fc-timeGridDay-button fc-button fc-button-primary" type="button">Día</button></div></div></div><div class="fc-view-harness fc-view-harness-active" style="height: 656.296px;"><div class="fc-timegrid fc-timeGridWeek-view fc-view"><table class="fc-scrollgrid  fc-scrollgrid-liquid"><thead><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-header "><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness"><div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><table class="fc-col-header " style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><th class="fc-timegrid-axis"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame"></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">lun 24/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">mar 25/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">mié 26/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">jue 27/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">vie 28/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">sáb 29/6</a></div></th><th class="fc-col-header-cell fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><a class="fc-col-header-cell-cushion ">dom 30/6</a></div></th></tr></tbody></table></div></div></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-body "><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness"><div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><div class="fc-daygrid-body fc-daygrid-body-unbalanced fc-daygrid-body-natural" style="width: 884px;"><table class="fc-scrollgrid-sync-table" style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-axis fc-scrollgrid-shrink"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame fc-timegrid-axis-frame-liquid"><span class="fc-timegrid-axis-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">Todo el día</span></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td><td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div></div><div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section"><td class="fc-timegrid-divider fc-cell-shaded"></td></tr><tr class="fc-scrollgrid-section fc-scrollgrid-section-body  fc-scrollgrid-section-liquid"><td><div class="fc-scroller-harness fc-scroller-harness-liquid"><div class="fc-scroller fc-scroller-liquid-absolute" style="overflow: hidden scroll;"><div class="fc-timegrid-body" style="width: 884px;"><div class="fc-timegrid-slots"><table class="" style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="00:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">0</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="00:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="00:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="00:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="01:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">1</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="01:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="01:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="01:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="02:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">2</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="02:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="02:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="02:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="03:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">3</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="03:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="03:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="03:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="04:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">4</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="04:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="04:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="04:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="05:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">5</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="05:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="05:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="05:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="06:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">6</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="06:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="06:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="06:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="07:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">7</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="07:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="07:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="07:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="08:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">8</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="08:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="08:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="08:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="09:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">9</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="09:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="09:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="09:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="10:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">10</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="10:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="10:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="10:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="11:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">11</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="11:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="11:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="11:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="12:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">12</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="12:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="12:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="12:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="13:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">13</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="13:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="13:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="13:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="14:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">14</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="14:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="14:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="14:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="15:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">15</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="15:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="15:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="15:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="16:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">16</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="16:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="16:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="16:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="17:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">17</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="17:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="17:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="17:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="18:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">18</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="18:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="18:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="18:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="19:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">19</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="19:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="19:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="19:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="20:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">20</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="20:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="20:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="20:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="21:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">21</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="21:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="21:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="21:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="22:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">22</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="22:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="22:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="22:30:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-scrollgrid-shrink" data-time="23:00:00"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-slot-label-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion">23</div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane " data-time="23:00:00"></td></tr><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-label fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="23:30:00"></td><td class="fc-timegrid-slot fc-timegrid-slot-lane fc-timegrid-slot-minor" data-time="23:30:00"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-timegrid-cols"><table style="width: 884px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 61px;"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-timegrid-axis"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-24"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-past" data-date="2024-06-25"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-past" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (10:00-10:30) at 25-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-today " data-date="2024-06-26"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 517px 0% -564px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">11:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (11:00-11:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 517px 0% -564px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">11:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (11:00-11:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Farrukito</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 752px 0% -799px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-today fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">16:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (16:00-16:30) at 26-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-27"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:00-10:30) at 27-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: </div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 501px 0% -548px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:40</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:40-11:00) at 27-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-28"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Afeitado -  (10:00-10:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Matias - Cliente: Miguel</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 470px 0% -517px 50%; z-index: 2;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">10:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (10:00-10:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: hugo</div></div></div></div></a></div><div class="fc-timegrid-event-harness fc-timegrid-event-harness-inset" style="inset: 799px 0% -846px; z-index: 1;"><a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future" style="border-color: rgb(60, 179, 113); background-color: rgb(60, 179, 113);"><div class="fc-event-main"><div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">17:00</div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">Corte de Niño -  (17:00-17:30) at 28-06-2024, Personal: Ezequiel - Cliente: Federico</div></div></div></div></a></div></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-29"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td><td class="fc-timegrid-col fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2024-06-30"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-frame"><div class="fc-timegrid-col-bg"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-col-events"></div><div class="fc-timegrid-now-indicator-container"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>




El sistema me dijo que esta era una respuesta demasiado extensa, yo no lo veía y no lo entendía... hasta que empecé a hacer scroll horizontal

@AlvaroMontoro Ahora que lo dices, me parecía raro no tener que inicializar el fullcalendar con JS, y claro!! Lo que está es el html generado

Gracias @Yussef. Por alguna razon, no me funciona. Aqui funciona esta idea tan genial, pero al añadir el css, no funciona. El Scritp del calendario tiene evento Clicky no se como hacer que funcione el ccs que me has proporcionado. En cualquier sitio funciona, pero no e al añadirlo en la sección de css.
¿quia deberia añadirlo directamente en el Script o cambiar el evento?
Aqui ten el script en codepen

@MiguelEspeso prueba con height: max-content !important; quizás eso solucione el problema. De lo contrario me avisas a ver si se me ocurre otra cosa

Solucionado. Primero, al no tener opciones, añadi la libreria Tippy.js, pero como también tenia que drlo estilos css, elimine el codigo de Tippyy utilice lo tuyo, cree un nuevo archivo css para incluir estos estilos y lo llame desde calendar: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/admin/css/mis-styles.css'); ?>">Gracias por tu dedicación, muchas gracias @Yusset. Seguire traytando de perfeccionarlo, no me gusta el resultado. Quiero que segun el personal seleccionado en la cita, la caja se muestren de un color diferente.. ¿que opinas, complicado?

@MiguelEspeso Que bueno que al final pudiste resolverlo!! Sobre el tema del color, puedes asignar una clase css al evento, según alguna propiedad https://fullcalendar.io/docs/classname-input

Si, vere como creo un distintivo para cada miembro del personal. La cosa es , ¿eso deberia de hacerlo en este mismo archivo? es mi duda, por eso te pregunte

@MiguelEspeso Si te refieres al agregar las nuevas clases con colores para los eventos en assets/admin/css/mis-styles.css. Pienso que sí, ese sería el lugar lógico para agregarlas

BNO, quiero decir a la funcionalidad de dar colores diferentes a la citas de cada miembro del personal: Uno rojo, otro azul, y otro verde. El archivo que te preguntaba, era el de el Script de Calendar que ve en el enlace de Codepen. No se si plantearlo con php o javascript. Pero tampoco te quiero liar. Voy a probar cosas y si no encuentro solución, volvere por stack en busca de ayuda
